# I made this colorbar but now I can't apply it to my contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, colorbar

I made this colorbar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)

cmap = mpl.cm.viridis
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)

cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap,
                                norm=norm,
                                orientation='horizontal')
cb1.set_label('Some Units')
fig.show()
```

[image]

but I am trying to apply this colorbar to this colormap of random variables using plt.contourf (I need to use plt.contourf for my actual data set, so I cannot use plt.imshow. I know plt.imshow does the correct colormap but in this case, I cannot use plt.imshow).

```
data = np.random.rand(100,200,144)

x = plt.contourf(data[-1],cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Why is the colorbar not going from 0 - 1 but has the intervals from 0 - 1.05? How do I replicate the created colorbar (cb1) to apply it to the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.contourf()` seems to do some rounding to have "nice" values for its levels. You could explicitly set your levels, for example `levels=np.linspace(0, 1, 11)` to obtain `10` regions (`11` region edges).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

cmap = mpl.cm.viridis
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)

data = np.random.rand(100, 200, 144)
cntr = plt.contourf(data[-1], cmap=cmap, norm=norm, levels=np.linspace(0, 1, 11))
plt.colorbar(cntr)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]